# Error using Object Initializer syntax to create MultiMatchQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Nest 2.2.0 and am trying to build a multimatch query as follows:

```
var searchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery() 
{
    Fields = Field<Product>(p=>p.SKUName, 2),
    Query = "hello world"
};
```

When I run it however, it returns:

> The non-generic type 'Nest.Field' cannot be used with type arguments.

I don't understand why I'm getting the error, since I've more or less taken this query straight from the documentation found at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/multi-match-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_35.

In case it matters, I've defined the Product as follows:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name="product", IdProperty="Id")]
public class Product
{
    [Nest.Number(Store = true)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [String(Name="name", Store = true, Index=FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string SKUName { get; set; }
}
```

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Field` type you're looking for is [`Nest.Infer.Field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#nest-infer)

```
var searchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery()
{
    Fields = Nest.Infer.Field<Product>(p => p.SKUName, 2),
    Query = "hello world"
};

client.Search<Product>(new SearchRequest { Query = searchQuery });
```

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: Thanksssss a lot . But I found the documentation of nest and es a little difficult to  identify .